# I can't access my computer properly without safe mode.

Tags: windows-10, updates, file-corruption, safe-mode

I've done everything and I can confirm that the reason my computer is somehow broken is not because of a virus. I have used malware-bytes, hit-man pro and I have removed everything that was remotely close to a virus. I'm scared that I might have to go and reinstall windows which requires me to buy a disc.

I scanned my computer with the scannow function and it said

"Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not supported in offline servicing scenarios."

So I went and input the thing and got a pop up. I'm hoping that the reason my computer is not working correctly is in the notepad and someone could point out the problem here.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/2a57dpk38zdjp2w/CBS.log

Someone help I'm desperate for any sort of help. I want to go back to playinh Minecraft and I cant access my graphic drivers or Audio in safemode with networking. I need to go back to regular mode. Regular mode is literally a black screen as soon as I sign in.

Comment: It's up to you. But I'd remove that last paragraph - it's not relevant to the problem. Do you have a legal installation of Windows? If that is the case, you can download the official installation media from Microsoft and reinstall. There is nothing to buy. Any number of things could be wrong. It's probably too broad of a question to answer. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: *"...and I have removed everything that was remotely close to a virus."*  Can you please elaborate?  Did Malwarebytes and/or HitmanPro actually find anything?

Comment: What do you see that indicates the computer is broken exactly? Google is a nice tool: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/reset-windows-10-pc and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/sfc-scannow-found-some-errors-but-was-unable-to/489238dd-24a5-49f1-af67-a5fa612e3051?auth=1 are two good starting points based on the cbs.log file I suppose but it's still not clear what you saw that indicated you needed to run `sfc /scannow` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The two simplest options:

- Restore from your last good disk image using rescue media (not booting from the HDD).
- Reinstall Windows 10. *Usually*, that can be done while retaining most files. Some programs may have to be reinstalled, though. Microsoft makes this fairly simple by providing [both an ISO image and tools to put it on external media, such as a USB drive.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326?auth=1) If you have network access in Safe Mode, then you can do this from your PC.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you face was likely caused by power failure or drive corruption during Windows update. Instead of reinstalling Windows which is more of a work around than a solution try repairing it.

First run CMD as admin and run

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Once that completes run

SFC /scannow

This will redownload any componants it finds to be corrupt instead of using the systems store (which might also be corrupt) This should make your computer bootable again but it may not fix Windows Update. My experience is that sometimes Windows update will also be corrupt usually resulting in checking for updates forever.